# Expression.Switch() struggling on case implementation

Tags: c#, expression

I'm trying to implement the `Expression.Switch()` to create a switch statement within my expressions. I'm struggling with some issues.

I've created a small example that raises the exception. The switch uses a string to switch the cases and within that case it will assign a variable.

Here is some code that will raise the exception:

```
// an int variable
var var1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
// a string variable
var var2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));

var cases = new[] 
{ 
    // the first case 'SwitchCaseValue1' should write the int value 1 into variable var1
    Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Assign(var1, Expression.Constant(1)), Expression.Constant("SwitchCaseValue1")),
    // the second case 'SwitchCaseValue2' should write the string value 'Example' into variable var2 
    Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Assign(var2, Expression.Constant("Example")), Expression.Constant("SwitchCaseValue2"))
};

Expression.Switch(Expression.Constant("SwitchValue"), cases);
```

This will raise this excepion: `All case bodies and the default body must have the same type.`

I think this refers to the `Assign` returning for case 1 an int and for case 2 a string. **How can i return nothing?**

---

If I change the `var2` to type int:

```
// an int variable
var var1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
// a string variable
var var2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

var cases = new[] 
{ 
    // the first case 'SwitchCaseValue1' should write the int value 1 into variable var1
    Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Assign(var1, Expression.Constant(1)), Expression.Constant("SwitchCaseValue1")),
    // the second case 'SwitchCaseValue2' should write the string value 'Example' into variable var2 
    Expression.SwitchCase(Expression.Assign(var2, Expression.Constant(2)), Expression.Constant("SwitchCaseValue2"))
};

Expression.Switch(Expression.Constant("SwitchValue"), cases);
```

It raises exception: `Default body must be supplied if case bodies are not System.Void.`

So i changed: the last line to
`Expression.Switch(Expression.Constant("SwitchValue"), Expression.Constant(0), cases);`

**This will compile. but is not what I'm looking for...**

---

**Is there another way to fix this first solution without implementing extra code to return the same type?**

I don't like solutions like selecting a meaningless return value, like:

```
// an int variable
var var1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
// a string variable
var var2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));

var cases = new[] 
{ 
    // the first case 'SwitchCaseValue1' should write the int value 1 into variable var1
    Expression.SwitchCase(
        Expression.Block( 
            Expression.Assign(var1, Expression.Constant(1)), 
            // return a boolean
            Expression.Constant(true)), 
        Expression.Constant("SwitchCaseValue1")),
    // the second case 'SwitchCaseValue2' should write the string value 'Example' into variable var2 
    Expression.SwitchCase(
        Expression.Block( 
            Expression.Assign(var2, Expression.Constant("Example")), 
            // return a boolean
            Expression.Constant(true)), 
        Expression.Constant("SwitchCaseValue2"))
};


Expression.Switch(Expression.Constant("SwitchValue"), Expression.Constant(false), cases);
```

---

I understand the logic of Expressions and returning a value. But is there a way to avoid implementing meaningless code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I found the answer myself**

The `Expression.Switch()` has an overload `Switch(Type type, Expression switchValue, Expression defaultBody, MethodInfo comparison, IEnumerable<SwitchCase> cases);`

When using this overload and passing `typeof(void)` into the parameter `type`, it will accept it.

msdn: *"All SwitchCase objects in a SwitchExpression object must have the same type, unless the SwitchExpression has the type void."* I didn't make the connection between the *SwitchExpression type* and an overload containing a *type* parameter.

This will do the job:

```
// an int variable
var var1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
// a string variable
var var2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));

var cases = new[] 
{ 
    // the first case 'SwitchCaseValue1' should write the int value 1 into variable var1
    Expression.SwitchCase(
            Expression.Assign(var1, Expression.Constant(1)), 
            Expression.Constant("SwitchCaseValue1")),
    // the second case 'SwitchCaseValue2' should write the string value 'Example' into variable var2 
    Expression.SwitchCase(
            Expression.Assign(var2, Expression.Constant("Example")), 
            Expression.Constant("SwitchCaseValue2"))
};

Expression.Switch(typeof(void), Expression.Constant("SwitchValue"), null, null, cases);
```